# Trying Populate DataGridView or DataTable from a CSV, which is an embedded resource

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

Well, been trying to do this for some time now and have been searching through loads of sites for a clue but no luck.

I am trying to populate either a DataTable or a DataGridView with a comma delimited CSV I have added as a resource (drag-drop on vb.net-2013 resource window).

I have managed to get the DataGridView columns to show the first line from CSV, not the rest though. CSV looks like:

```
"id,city,loc,lat,lon,chk,tst,sob,completed,1,charlotte,dock,0000.0,0000.0,,,,,,2,Chicago,..."
```

Whenever I try populating the rows I get an error:

```
    Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table.
```

There are 9 columns and about 700k rows, first row is col names.

Thanks for any help.

Here's what I have so far:

```
        Dim tbl = New DataTable
        Dim lines() As String = My.Resources.CityLocation.Split(CChar(Environment.NewLine))
        Dim colCount = lines.First.Split(","c).Length
        Dim col = Split(lines(0), ","c)
        Dim rowCount = lines.GetLength(0)

        'Populating the Column Headers
        For i = 0 To colCount - 1
            tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn(col(i), GetType(String)))
        Next

        ''Populating the Rows
        'For i = 1 To rowCount
        '    For Each line In lines
        '        Dim theRow = From field In line.Split(","c)
        '        Dim Array() = theRow.ToArray
        '        Dim newRow = tbl.Rows.Add()
        '        newRow.ItemArray = Array
        '    Next
        'Next
```

`

Comment: Why isn't this a database?

Comment: According to your example there are way more than 9 columns.

Comment: @OneFineDay thanks for your input. I wish it were on a database but unfortunately I don't control the creation of the CSV file, it's just handed down to me. The first 9 fields are the columns. When I get the text from the CSV, after it has been embedded, I think it loses its line breaks so it looks like one continuous line.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use a `TextFieldParser`.  If you've embedded a text file as a resource then it will be returned as a `String`.  You can create a `StringReader` on that.  A `StringReader` is like a `StreamReader` but for reading `String`s instead of `Stream`s.  You can then create a `TextFieldParser` on that.

```
Using reader As New StringReader(My.Resources.CityLocation),
      parser As New TextFieldParser(reader)
    '...
End Using
```

If you check out the MSDN documentation for the `TextFieldParser` class, you'll find an example of how to use one to read CSV data.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out.